# Qt5: Problems with german Umlaute (ä, ö, ü char) and QStrings

Tags: qt

I have a problem with Qt5, QStrings and german Umlaute like ä, ö and ü-char. I read data of a 1024 byte header, display it in a form in my app and edit some entries. Everytime I write a german Umlaut in a QLineEdit and process it, I get 2 Bytes instead of 1 Byte - because QString does need 2 Bytes for each character since Qt5.

I've tried this:

```
QString str = rs_Position1_QLE->text();
QByteArray ba = str.toLatin1();
qDebug() << "ba:" << ba;
```

Console: ba: "S\xF6ndenlabor" the \xF6 stands for the char ö
(saving the file with the header results in EF BF BD for the ö instead of F6)

but even then I get 2 Bytes for every character with an ASCII Code higher than 127.

How can I solve my problem?

Thank you very much for your answers!
Ralf

Sorry for the delay! I've made a little example script and hope that helps:

```
Stringtest::Stringtest(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent) {

    this->setWindowTitle("Stringtest");

    QWidget *window = new QWidget;
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;

    QPushButton *OpenFile_QPB = new QPushButton("Open File");
    OpenFile_QPB->setFixedSize(100, 50);

    Content_QLE = new QLineEdit;
    Content_QLE->setMaxLength(20);
    Content_QLE->setMinimumWidth(200);
    Content_QLE->setMaximumWidth(200);
    Content_QLE->setStyleSheet("padding: 5px; font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Arial', 'Verdana'; font-size: 12px; background-color: white;
border: none; ");

    QPushButton *SaveToFile_QPB = new QPushButton("Save to File");
    SaveToFile_QPB->setFixedSize(100, 50);

    layout->addWidget(OpenFile_QPB);
    layout->addWidget(Content_QLE);
    layout->addWidget(SaveToFile_QPB);

    window->setLayout(layout);
    this->setCentralWidget(window);

    connect(OpenFile_QPB, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(OpenFile()));

}

Stringtest::~Stringtest() { }

void
Stringtest::OpenFile() {

    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open file", "C://Semroch.R", "Textfiles (*.txt);; All files (*.*)");

    if (fileName.isEmpty())
        return;
    else {
        QFile file(fileName);
        file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
        qDebug() << "system name:"      << QLocale::system().name();
        qDebug() << "codecForLocale:"   << QTextCodec::codecForLocale()->name();
        while (!file.atEnd()) {
            QByteArray qbaLine = file.readLine();
            qDebug() << qbaLine;
            Content_QLE->setText(qbaLine);
            // QString strLine = qbaLine;
            // Content_QLE->setText(strLine);
        }
    }

} // End of void Stringtest::OpenFile()
```

I have a test.txt, which I load into the script - the content of the textfile is abcdefä.
The display in the QLineEdit is:
abcdef and a question mark in a diamond.
The qDebug() shows me
system name: "de_DE"
codecForLocale: "System"
in the console.

Any ideas? Thank you very much, Ralf

Comment: Show us the code you use for saving the files.

Comment: Hi Benjamin, sorry for the delay - I've written a little testscript. You could see it above. Thank you! Ralf

Answer (score 0):

Few possibilities:

- Be sure your shell handles utf-8 (if `echo -e '\xe2\x82\xac'` command doesn't show a `€`, then you should fix your shell)
- Be sure to handle UTF-8 correctly in your application (add those lines in your `main()` function):

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
QTextCodec::setCodecForTr(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: I think this is unrelated - he tries to write user input as latin1 to a file, not fix the qDebug() output.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to understand is that `QByteArray` is just a collection of bytes, it says nothing about its content or the encoding used, while `QString` is a unicode string stored as UTF-16.

So when you do `Content_QLE->setText(qbaLine)` or `QString strLine = qbaLine`, you are implicitly converting a `QByteArray` to a `QString`. According to [QString documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QString-8), it calls `QString::fromUtf8()`.

So if your file is not encoded as UTF-8, but as Latin 1, you will have issues.
If your file is in Latin 1, you should do: `Content_QLE->setText(QString::fromLatin1(qbaLine))`

The same goes, when you are writing a file:

```
file.write(str.toUtf8()); // Write to a UTF-8 file
file.write(str.toLatin1()); // Write to a Latin 1 file
```

Comment: Hi Benjamin, thank you very much! Have tried to fill in my QLineEdit using fromLatin1 and it works! Will try writing to a file tomorrow... Thanks!